# I was using a linux terminal to select a bigint column from another windows sql server(by php mmsql)

Tags: php, x86-64, windows-server, bigint

I was using a linux terminal to select a bigint column from another windows sql server(by php mmsql), but the result turn to be a float number.. why..

the sql is:

```
SELECT cAccountId FROM tAccountMaster WHERE cUserString = 'xxxx';
```

it should be :

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["cAccountId"]=> bigint(60254406962323528) } }
```

but it turn out to be :

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["cAccountId"]=> float(6.0254406962324E+16) } }
```

Here is the database structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you show your `tAccountMaster` structure and which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: the structure has been posted. please..

Comment: put it on your question not as an answer.

Comment: Are your `PHP` & OS _both_ 64 bit? If not, you may want to cast to char (which is not a bad idea for ID's application side anyway). I for one don't see a datatype for `bigint`'s @ [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.constants.php)

Comment: thank you , the problem have been solved by using convert 'SELECT convert(string,cAccountId) FROM tAccountMaster WHERE cUserString = 'xxxx';'  , just like cast.